# ¿Como puedo hacer que al apretar un boton aparezca un simbolo de carga?

Tags: javascript

Mi situación es la siguiente, tengo un piedra, papel o tijeras con Js y botoncitos de piedra, papel o tijeras respectivamente. Quiero que al apretar alguno de los botones espere unos segundos y a la vez aparezca un gif de un símbolo de carga, y ejecute la función que llama el boton despúes de ese proceso. Por acá mi HTML, JS y CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Piedra papel o tijera</title>
    <script src="Piedra, papel o tijeras.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Ceeseese.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60b90458fd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Texto">
      <p><strong>Elige tu opcion</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Btns">
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(0)"><i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>Tijera</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(1);"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>Piedra</a>
    <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(2);"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>Papel</a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
Y ahora mi javascript:

function Opcion(miOpcion) {
  var nombre = ["Tijera","Piedra","Papel"]
  var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 0 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 1)
{
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Ganaste, sos un capo")
}
else if(miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 1 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 0)
{
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Perdiste, sos un pete")
}
else {
  alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
  alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
  alert("Empataste")
}
}
```

Tambíen tengo CSS, si es necesario, me lo dicen.

Comment: Podrías usar el `setTimeOut ` y hacer que aparezca el GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Se necesita un *spinner*, puedes usar el de [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/spinners/). Además, como te comentaron, se logra usando la función `setTimeout()`.

Modificando tu código, así quedaría.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Piedra papel o tijera</title>
        <script src="Piedra, papel o tijeras.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Ceeseese.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60b90458fd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Agregamos bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="game">
            <div class="Texto">
                <p><strong>Elige tu opcion</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Btns">
                <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(0)"><i class="fas fa-hand-scissors"></i>Tijera</a>
                <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(1);"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock"></i>Piedra</a>
                <a href="#" class="Botones" onclick="Opcion(2);"><i class="fas fa-hand-paper"></i>Papel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loading" style="display: none">
            <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function Opcion(miOpcion) {
            document.getElementById("game").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
            // Con esta función logramos que se ejecute despues de 2 segundos (2000 milisegundos)
            setTimeout(function () {
                var nombre = ["Tijera", "Piedra", "Papel"]
                var cpu = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
                if (miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 0 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 1) {
                    alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
                    alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
                    alert("Ganaste, sos un capo")
                }
                else if (miOpcion === 0 && cpu === 1 || miOpcion === 1 && cpu === 2 || miOpcion === 2 && cpu === 0) {
                    alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
                    alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
                    alert("Perdiste, sos un pete")
                }
                else {
                    alert("Jugador: " + nombre[miOpcion]);
                    alert("Contrincante: " + nombre[cpu]);
                    alert("Empataste")
                }
                document.getElementById("game").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    
            }, 2000);
        }
    </script>
    
    </html>
```